# How to make a temporary output

Tags: python, printing, output

I want to print an output 'temporary', which is actually like this;

```
In[1]: print ("Hello")
Out[1]: Hello #Out[1]
#after 2 seconds for example
Out[1]: Hi #Still Out[1]
```

Is there any way to do this? It's like a sentence displaying for 2 seconds after then at the **same** location, display another string. Can we delete last output and print something else on the same line?

Answer (score 2):

I not sure if we can go back and 'un-print' something we've already printed, but just like on a real world typewriter, we can use [carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return), to reset 'printer' to the start of the line and re-print something else.

This code demonstrates how it works (it's a bad infinite loop just for this demonstration). Notice the '\r' after %d,

```
i = 0
while time.sleep(0.2) == None:
    sys.stdout.write("Counter: %d\r" %i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    i += 1
```

Comment: Well at least you understand my problem thanks for answer. Are you sure is that not possible `un-print` ?

Comment: @qwerty- I guess we will have to define 'un-print', because when we carriage return and then print a '\n', we essentially erased the previously printed line :D

Comment: @techolic '\n' would move the carriage to the new line. '\r' would move the carriage to the beginning of the current line thus new text output will overwrite what has been outputted previously. So if new text output is shorter than the previous then those characters will remain. Use space ' ' or many spaces to overwrite as a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Use [time.sleep()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) module
.This simple code will work on python console, but **not** Ipython console nor Ipython Notebook.

```
def hello():
    print 'Hello',
    time.sleep(2)
    print '\rHi'

hello()
```

This will work on Ipython Notebook, but not Ipython Console

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
def hello():
    print 'Hello'
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(2)
    clear_output()
    print 'Hi'
    sys.stdout.flush()
hello()
```

Comment: I want to display it at the same location. See it's still `Out[1]` in my question. Read carefully please

Comment: This answer is really funny `use sleep()` . You have to read question carefully.

Comment: @qwerty- You cannot Output to the same line as you type! You have to make a function for it. So you only have to input in one line and then it will output in one line.

Comment: @dragon2fly  You still don't understand the question. I'm experienced with Python so please read the question again.

Comment: @qwerty- You have to try with '\rHi' but there is no warranty that it will work in Ipython in all machine. But it will do exactly what you want in normal console.

Comment: @dragon2fly Is your codes delete the last output and putting new output there? NO. You still trying to use `sleep`.

Comment: @qwerty- don't you get it! `sleep` give you 2 secs of waiting, nothing more! `'\rHi'` will first clear the row and then put `Hi` at the place of `Hello`. And it will do exactly that if you make a .py file and run it from there. Nothing to be sure that it will work in all Ipython console!

Comment: @qwerty-/howaboutno You really need to read the answer. Dragon2fly clearly knows what you are asking here. Forget the sleep for a second, and look at the rest.